# Time reversibility of stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

For Ito SDE
$$ dx = f(x,t)dt + g(x,t)dw$$

It transforms initial distribution $p(x_0)$ to distribution $p(x_T)$ at time $T$. My question is whether or not there exists a "reverse" sde $dx = f'(x,t)dt + g'(x,t)dw$ such that if the initial distribution is $q(x_0)=p(x_T)$, the transformed distribution at time $T$ under the sde is $q(x_T)=p(x_0)$. Under which assumption, such "reverse" sde exists and what are $f',g'$?

My naive guess is
$$
dx = [f(x,T-t) + g(x,T-t)g^T(x,T-t)\nabla log q(x_T|x_0)]dt + g(x,T-t)dw
$$
But I am not sure about correctness and under what assumptions such "reverse" sde exists.

Update:
My previous question only requires end marginals. It should be $ q(x_{T-t})=p(x_t) $.

Comment: That would mean to reverse entropy. Both processes are dissipative, both widen the distribution.

Comment: Notation is crappy. What you likely mean is it transforms an initial distribution, say  $p_{0}$, to some distribution $p_{T}$ at time $T$. Now, regarding you question I suggest you dig into literaturem focussing on key word: Doob's transform, h-transform, bridges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question was motivated by the recent wave of (denoising) diffusion models in generative modelling in ML.
Here are some links I found useful for the math background of the reverse time SDE.

https://ludwigwinkler.github.io/blog/ReverseTimeAnderson/

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414982900515

Comment: This is a link only answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The first blog solves my question!